# Change event is not getting trigger when updating model in backbone js

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

I have a view called layerPanel that is using screenData model. Now on model.set i get update event from model itself, but its not working on view.

**MODEL**

```
var screenData = Backbone.Model.extend({


 initialize  : function() {
    _.bindAll(this,"update");
    this.bind('change:vdata', this.update);
},

update: function() {
var obj = this.vdata;
    alert("update");
},

vdata:[{id : 0, title : "Welcome to Persieve 0"}]

});
```

**VIEW**

```
   var layerPanel = Backbone.View.extend({

            el: "#allLayers",
            model: new screenData(),


            initialize: function() {
                this.render();
            this.model.bind('change:vdata', this.render);
            },
  render: function() {
              this.template = _.template(LayersTpl, {splitData: this.model.vdata});
              this.$el.html(this.template);
              return this;
            }
        });
```

Here is how I set values in Model.

```
    screendata = new screenData;
    var obj = screendata.vdata;
    obj[obj.length] = {id : $(".bullet").length, title : "Welcome to Persieve"};
    var tempData = [];
    for ( var index=0; index<obj.length; index++ ) {
    if ( obj[index]) {
        tempData.push( obj );
    }
    }
   obj = tempData;
   screendata.set({vdata:[obj]});
```

Comment: Can you show more of your value setting code? Do you set the model of the layerPanel to the new model you create in the first line of the last snippet?

Comment: Matt, I've added code for setting values in Model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The event should fire. But your render wont work as the 'this' context needs setting.

try:

```
this.model.bind('change:vdata', this.render, this);
```

or even better, use listenTo and the context is implicit (+ you can clean up easily this.remove())

Edit. From the edit you made above, I can see that you are creating a new screendata instance. The binding you created is for a different instance `model: new screenData()` .

You must reference the binded object and set it if you want the event to trigger.

If all the model setting happens in the actual model. Call `this.set({vdata:[obj]});`

Comment: This is also not working. I've tried listenTo, still no luck. Actually I figured out that event itself is not triggering. I put some another function rather than render, but its also not calling.

Comment: I've created global object for Model and modifying it, this is working fine now, thx.